# Application fails to start when I add a custom method in Repository interface

Tags: sql, reactjs, spring-boot, controller, sts

My application runs fine when it doesn't include any custom method in Repository. The moment I add a custom repo method in repo interface, it gives exceptions and application fails to start.

```
package com.library.repo;

import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Query;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import com.library.entity.ShowEntity;

@Repository
public interface ShowRepository extends JpaRepository<ShowEntity, Integer> {

    
    @Query("SELECT s FROM show_entity s WHERE s.movie.movie_id = :movieId")
    List<ShowEntity> findShowsByMovieId(int movieId);

}
```

Console message:

```
Error creating bean with name 'showController' defined in file [/Users/PR20372898/Documents/workspace-spring-tool-suite-4-4.15.1.RELEASE/XYZCinemas/target/classes/com/library/controller/ShowController.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0: 

Error creating bean with name 'showService' defined in file [/Users/PR20372898/Documents/workspace-spring-tool-suite-4-4.15.1.RELEASE/XYZCinemas/target/classes/com/library/service/ShowService.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0: Error creating bean with name 'showRepository' defined in com.library.repo.ShowRepository defined in @EnableJpaRepositories declared on JpaRepositoriesRegistrar.EnableJpaRepositoriesConfiguration: 

Could not create query for public abstract java.util.List com.library.repo.ShowRepository.findShowsByMovieId(int); Reason: Validation failed for query for method public abstract java.util.List com.library.repo.ShowRepository.findShowsByMovieId(int)
```

What could be the possible reasons for getting this problem? I have used all the annotations. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

The problem are in syntax, you have not written it in a right way.

The correct one:

```
@Query("SELECT s FROM ShowEntity s WHERE s.movie.movie_id = :movieId")
    List<ShowEntity> findShowsByMovieId(@Param("movieId") Integer movieId);
```

To have more details about it you have to read the [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like there may be a bug in your query syntax. If you are trying to select all columns from the `show_entity` table, the syntax should be:

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM show_entity s WHERE s.movie.movie_id = :movieId")
List<ShowEntity> findShowsByMovieId(@Param("movieId") int movieId);
```

Comment: Do I have to use table name or class name here: 
"SELECT * FROM show_entity"
??

Comment: `SELECT * ...`, `SELECT s.* ...`, and `SELECT s ...` are all equivalent in the query you asked about. You do not need the table name in this case.

Comment: SELECT * ... is a native query so you have to add nativeQuery parameter

Answer (score 0):

The Spring Data JPA already provides support to dervied queries based on method names. That can directly be used in this case as shown below to retrieve records by movie ID.

```
@Repository
public interface ShowRepository extends JpaRepository<ShowEntity, Integer> {
    List<ShowEntity> findByMovieId(int movieId);
}
```

But if you still wish to use the `@Query` annotation, you need to understand the difference between JPQL (Java Persistence Query Language) and native queries. The query can be rewritten in JPQL as:

```
@Query("SELECT s.* FROM ShowEntity s WHERE s.movieID = :movieId")
List<ShowEntity> findShowsByMovieId(@Param("movieId") int movieId);
```

And while using native query, the query should be updated as below:

```
@Query("SELECT s.* FROM show_entity s WHERE s.movie_id = :movieId", nativeQuery = true)
List<ShowEntity> findShowsByMovieId(@Param("movieId") int movieId);
```

I suggest that you go through the [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#jpa.query-methods) for deeper understanding on this topic.

Answer (score 0):

From [docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#jpa.query-methods.at-query)

```java
@Query("SELECT s FROM ShowEntity s WHERE s.movie_id = ?1")
List<ShowEntity> findShowsByMovieId(int movieId);
```

second way:

```java
@Query("SELECT * FROM show_entity s WHERE s.movie_id = :movieId", nativeQuery = true)
List<ShowEntity> findShowsByMovieId(@Param("movieId") int movieId);
```

Comment: if you feel it useful, please [vote up](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up) or accept answer